# Series expansion of potential due to a dipole displaced from the origin

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential, dipole, multipole-expansion

I learn that we can expand the electric potential in an infinite series of $\rho$ and $\cos(n \phi)$ when solving the Laplace equation in polar coordinates. The problem I want to consider is the expansion for the potential due to a 2D line dipole (two infinitely-long line charge separated by a small distance). In the attached image, I have written down the potential due to a line dipole (I'm pretty sure it's correct, at least the dot product and the dependence on $D$ and $r$). Now I place the perfect line dipole at a position $(-x_0,0)$, and I want to calculate the potential in terms of the infinite series. The problem is that the coefficient An is different depending on whether rho is bigger than or smaller than $x_0$ when I solve the integral using contour integral (again, pretty sure the definite integral is done correctly). At the 'imaginary' boundary of $\rho=x_0$, the potential calculated using the two different An should give the same results, but now they differ by a sign. Why is that? What have I done wrong?

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't there be a $\cos{m\phi}$ term in the integrand ?

Comment: yeah, you are right. I forgot to write it down, but the final result is still correct.